# Why does vim report error when i write data into page with ramfs

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I use my_do_sync_read and my_do_sync_write function to replace do_sync_read and do_sync_write in ramfs source code to encrypt data wrote into page. It is successful for writing a file from nano or block from dd instruction. But when I use vim to save a file , it fail to write and show: ml_upd_block0(): Didn't get block 0??
[image] .

following code is my simple test and got a same problem:

---

```
ssize_t my_do_sync_read(struct file *filp,  char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
{
  ssize_t size_ret; 
  int i;
  size_ret=do_sync_read(filp, buf, len, ppos);
  for(i=0;i<size_ret;i++)
      buf[i]^=0xff;
  return size_ret;
}

ssize_t my_do_sync_write(struct file *filp,  char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++)
      buf[i]^=0xff;
  return do_sync_write(filp, buf, len, ppos);
}
```

---

Comment: Please, do not post *images* of code, instead post the code itself (as **text**). See [ask].

Comment: `buf[i]^=0xff` is incorrect: 1. User-space pointer `buf` shouldn't be dereferenced directly, `copy_from_user`/`copy_to_user` should be used instead. 2. In `write` function buffer should be treated as **read-only** (its correct specification is `const char __user * buf`). Changing read-only data is not expected by application. Moreover, read-only data could be located in read-only memory, so reading them would cause fault. BTW, you should get a compiler warning about incompatible types of `.write` field in `file_operations` structure and your function. You are checking compiler warnings, right?

Comment: The write function buffer should be read-only,so I coundn't modify it . How can I encrypt  buffer data in ramfs layer?

Comment: You may copy user-space `buf` into temporary buffer, change content in that temporary buffer, and then pass that temporary buffer to `do_sync_write` function. But because temporary buffer would belong to kernel space, you need to wrap `do_sync_write` call with `set_fs(...)` magic.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your answer, that helped me a lot. But I still have a last question.I use AES 16 to encrypt the buffer data,but it is failure when I decrypt the reading buffer data. The AES 16 encryption is to encrypt 16 byte once. But the reading buffer and writting buffer length may be not divisible  by 16.   So it will cause that my writting  encrypted data will be cut a few byte data in the tail and decrypt the data is failure. How could  I sovle the problem?

Comment: You need to take into account `*ppos` parameter: Its value denotes the **offset** of the data written/read from the start of the file. So, if this offset is odd, you need to process the first byte in a special manner.